# Intelligently scale sprites for different screensizes in Andengine

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

Is there a smart way to scale sprites for different screensizes?

Im testing my game on a 1280*800 screen, however, when i try testing on a 800*480 i would like to scale the sprites so its the same experience but with worse gfx.

Comment: We have discuss the same thing here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50165/how-do-i-support-variable-screen-ratios-using-andengine

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with AndEngine, but to scale your sprite I think you got 2 options. 
One is to scale your resources and have 2 sets of sprites, one for 1280x800 and one for 800x480.

Another way is to draw your sprites relative to the base resolution 800x480 and use a scale factor or 1.6 or somthing like that when you have a bigger resolution. Also set the scale for the sprite accordingly.